# 'ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME' is not set on Cloud Endpoints with Firebase auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

When I call my API as:

> PUT https://[Project-id].appspot.com/_ah/api/person/v2/[id]/thanks?thanks=true

The response is a **400 BadRequest**.

```
{
 "error": {
    "errors": [
        {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest",
        "message": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Environment variable 'ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME' is not set"
        }
     ],
     "code": 400,
     "message": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Environment variable 'ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME' is not set"
  }
}
```

The response should be **401 Unauthorized**, because i use Authentification with Firebase.

The Api definition:

```
 @Api(
    name = "person",
    version="v2",
    authenticators = {EspAuthenticator.class},
    issuers = {
            @ApiIssuer(
                    name = "firebase",
                    issuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/[Project-id] ",
                    jwksUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com")
    },
    issuerAudiences = {
            @ApiIssuerAudience(name = "firebase", audiences = "[Project-id] ")
    }
    )
```

And the Api method:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "thanks",path = "{personId}/thanks",httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.PUT)
public Object thanks(@Named("personId") String personId, @Named("thanks") Boolean thanks, User user) throws IOException, NotFoundException, UnauthorizedException {
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException("Invalid credentials");
    }

    MyBean ty= new MyBean(thanks);
    return ty;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are using the Endpoints Java Framework. You need to set the ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME in the appengineweb.xml file:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/endpoints-frameworks-v2/backend/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml#L31